# Regular expression in mysql to answer the given query

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

my mysql table has a column structure that dumps various attributes which is separated by ";"
for each of the element of a html file.

```
+-----------+------------------------------------+
| tag_id    | attributes                         |
+-----------+------------------------------------+
|  1        |class:block_22;id:toc_id_35;        |
|  2        |class:bloack_1000;id:12#4           |
+-----------+------------------------------------+
```

I want to write a query that selects the rows that have

```
  1.id attribute that starts with #
  2.id attribute that ends with #
  3.id attribute that has # in between
```

the first query can be answered this way

```
SELECT * FROM table where attributes like "%id:#%";
```

I am not sure of how to handle the other two queries .
Please give me some valuable insights.

Comment: Using strings like this in SQL is poor design. You should create an attribute-value table that puts each attribute in a separate row, with a foreign key to the `tag_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These patterns should do what you want:

```
where attribute regexp 'id:#'
where attribute regexp 'id:[^;]*#(;|$)'
where attribute regexp 'id:[^;]+#[^;]+'
```

Comment: I think the last two need to end with `(;|$)` because there may not be a `;` at the end.